# ofstream fails to open existing file

Tags: c++, windows, ofstream

While working with the OpenXcom app, I noticed that at some point the app stopped updating the `options.cfg` file.  I tracked this issue down to a failure creating an `ofstream` object for the `options.cfg` file in the `Options::save()` method.  A search uncovered no explanation for my issue.  The only solution I could find was to delete the `options.cfg` file and let the program recreate it with the default settings.

I have recreated what appears to be a similar issue with a very simple C++ program (modeled on the first few lines of the `Options::save()` method in the OpenXcom project):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void check(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ofstream stream(filename.c_str());

    if (!stream) {
        std::cout << "FAIL " << filename << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "PASS " << filename << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    check("options1.cfg");
    check("options2.cfg");
}
```

Using this test program, I created the following test case using the Command Prompt:

- Create a directory containing only the test program.
- Run the test program to create two empty `.cfg` files.
- Run the test program again to verify that the program can still work with both `.cfg` files.
- Delete `options2.cfg`
- Copy `options1.cfg` to `options2.cfg`
- Run the test program again.  Now the program can no longer create an `ofstream` object for the `options2.cfg` file.

Here is Command Prompt listing for the test case (which I have edited a bit to remove extraneous information):

```
C:\...\test>dir

12/19/2022  09:10 AM            27,648 ofstream-test.exe

C:\Users\jwlent\Documents\test>ofstream-test.exe
PASS options1.cfg
PASS options2.cfg

C:\...\test>dir

12/19/2022  09:10 AM            27,648 ofstream-test.exe
12/19/2022  02:39 PM                 0 options1.cfg
12/19/2022  02:39 PM                 0 options2.cfg

C:\...\test>ofstream-test.exe
PASS options1.cfg
PASS options2.cfg

C:\....\test>del options2.cfg

C:\....\test>copy options1.cfg options2.cfg
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\...\test>dir

12/19/2022  09:10 AM            27,648 ofstream-test.exe
12/19/2022  02:39 PM                 0 options1.cfg
12/19/2022  02:39 PM                 0 options2.cfg

C:\....\test>ofstream-test.exe
PASS options1.cfg
FAIL options2.cfg
```

Other things I noted:

- Closing the Command Prompt console and creating a new one did not change the result (i.e. allow the test program to create an `ofstream` object for the `options2.cfg` file).
- Closing the Command Prompt console and creating a new one with Admin authority did not change the result.
- A restart of my laptop did clear the issue.  Since a restart clears the issue, that would indicate that there is nothing wrong with the file permissions.
- There are several other ways to create this issue.  For example, manually creating the files using any editor.
- I used VS 2022 on a Win 10 laptop to create the test program.

Can anyone explain what may be going on?   Especially if there is a way to modify the test program to work around this issue in a way that can be applied to the `Options::save()` file in the OpenXcom project.

A few more observations:

- The problem can persist for many hours (overnight).
- While the problem persists, Python has no problem writing to the file from the same Command Prompt.

Here is the slightly edited Command Prompt output.

```
C:\...\test>ofstream-test.exe
PASS options1.cfg
FAIL options2.cfg
    
C:\...\test>python
Python 2.7.18 (v2.7.18:8d21aa21f2, Apr 20 2020, 13:25:05) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> f = open("options2.cfg", "w")
>>> f.write("overwrite")
>>> f.close()
>>> exit()
    
C:\...\test>ofstream-test.exe
PASS options1.cfg
FAIL options2.cfg
    
C:\...\test>more options2.cfg
 overwrite
```

Here is what Process Monitor recorded for the C++ program and then Python trying to open the file for write:

46:23.0 ofstream-test.exe   22396   CreateFile   C:\Users\jwlent\Documents\test\options2.cfg   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes, Disposition: OverwriteIf, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 0

46:39.9 python.exe           3000   CreateFile   C:\Users\jwlent\Documents\test\options2.cfg   SUCCESS         Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes, Disposition: OverwriteIf, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 0, OpenResult: Overwritten

Comment: I've tried replicating this and unfortunately I wasn't able to. My wild guess here is that this has something to do with file permissions on your system. I have other wild guesses but unfortunately without replicating this error I can't help you. EDIT: Have you tried disabling your antivirus? I once used to have similar problems with Avast AV. Had to fiddle with the config files for it to work properly.

Comment: use sysinternals procmon tool to see all the file io the ap does

Comment: I would guess that the `.cfg` file in question is likely open somewhere else (ie, probably an antivirus/antimalware, etc), and that open handle doesn't share write access to the file. That would explain why creating a new `ofstream` to the same file right away after creating/copying it is failing until you reboot the machine and then create the `ofstream` without first opening/creating the file again.  If the test fails, try waiting a few seconds and try again, maybe the file will have been released by then.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I played around with both the Process Monitor and the Process Explorer tools.  I have found no indication of any other process having access to the "options2.cfg" file.  I will try turning off antivirus code later.  I  saved the raw Process Monitor data if anyone is interested.

Comment: Not solved exactly, but better understood.  I finally noticed that the problem only occurred under certain directory patterns.  Specifically it fails in at least the following cases "C:\Users\*\Documents" and "C:\Users\*\Desktop".  I then stumbled across something called "Protected Directories".  I could not create the problem under "C:\junk".  But if I added that directory (including "sub folders") to "Protected Directories" the problem started occurring there too.  And when I removed that setting the problem went away.

Comment: Protected Directories appear to be a Windows Defender feature.  I am actually using Norton but it also seems to support the concept.  I need to research it a bit more.  OpenXcom writes its configuration file to a folder under "Documents" so with my setup it can trigger this issue.

Comment: For Windows OpenXcom will search for the options.cfg file in three different locations.  The last choice is the one explicitly under "Documents".  Adding a directory named "user" under "..\OpenXcom\bin\Win32\" will trigger the application to find/create the options.cfg file there instead.  With that change to the source code installation I can now run OpenXcom in debug mode (via VS) and swap in and out different versions of the options.cfg file without running into a write issue. Assuming of course the source code installation is itself not under a "Protected Folder".